# How can I add python to cmd in windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I have python 3.1 installed, and I have added it to the system path too. Now I can open "cmd" and type python to start python, but whenever I try to open cmd in a specific directory by using (shift + right click -> open command prompt here), and type python, it says "command not found"!

How can I fix this?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596505/python-not-working-in-command-prompt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set up the [environment variables](http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html#configuring-python) in Windows.

Answer (score 15):

Right click on my computer>got to properties>advanced settings>environmental variables>

> choose path and add the installed python dirtory to that path as like below:

C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Python27

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what the answer from 2 1/2 years ago already said.

Comment: @glglgl Yes. This is a better answer because it's easier than following an external link.