# Python not recognised as command

Tags: python, environment-variables, python-3.6

I know that I need to add Python to my `PATH` and I've tried to add it by copy and pasting its address `C:\Users\aiden\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.6` to my `PATH`, but when I try to use python in the command prompt, it is not recognized as a command.

Here an image of my PATH variable: [image]

Comment: What's your OS? Be sure to restart terminal after adding Python to PATH. If it keeps not working you could try to reinstall Python making sure you check the "Add Python 3.6 to PATH"

Comment: If you are on Windows, can you type in in cmd "print %PATH%" and see what comes out? you can compare the output to makes sure it shows the location of Python.exe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python not working in command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596505/python-not-working-in-command-prompt)

Comment: Try restarting your command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

It seems very unlikely that your python has been installed to the Start Menu path. Try

1. Right-click on your 'Python 3.6' in your start menu path and open file location
2. In the folder that appears, right-click on 'Python 3.6' and copy the text from 'Target'
3. Add the Target-text into 'system environment variables' where the variable name is 'Path'

You might need to logout and in again, for this to take affect.