# Python not working in command prompt after using suggestions on stackoverflow

Tags: python, command-line, git-bash

Current situation:

- Windows 7
- 64 Bit
- Using Gitbash shell within Visual Studio Code

Using the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596505/python-not-working-in-command-prompt), I have included `C:\Python27` within the PATH and PYTHONPATH system variables (NOTE: I had to create the PYTHONPATH system variable).

After doing this, I reran the command `python get-pip.py` and it still says the command is not found.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've made sure that Python 2.7 has been installed on my machine.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you re-run the command in the same windows command prompt or have you opened a new session?

Comment: I have opened a new session.