# Python cannot run in console mode

Tags: python, windows, console, git-bash

I use Anaconda3 installed python on Windows10.

When I run `python --version` in git-bash, it works.

```
$ python --version
Python 3.7.3
$ which python
/d/Programs/Anaconda3/python
```

But when I run `python`, it output nothing and pending there

```
$ python
```

A image may be more clear here.
[image]

I can input anything, when press, but nothing happens, just a new line.

```
$ python

print(1)
```

[image]

---

**Note** My issue is different from [Python not working in command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13596505/6521116) which is cannot find the python path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here has something to do with `git-bash` GUI. I cannot run it in `git-bash`, but I can run it in windows `cmd`.

Answer (score 1):

Try all your commands with `$ python3 ...` maybe you dont have installed the python 2 version which gets normaly called by `$ python ..`