# Python Version is not getting displayed in Command Prompt

Tags: python, cmd

I downloaded the recent version of python(3.8.3) and selected the 'ADD TO PATH' prompt during setup and it was successfully completed(I checked by running the python.exe file in the source folder) but when i type **'python'** or **'python --version'** to check which version I am running in the command prompt, it doesn't show anything.

Some of the posts online suggested, to add the path manually again in system variables under environment variables, I did that too but it didn't work. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling it several times but that didn't work too.

I am running Windows 10 Home 64-bit.
Please Help.
Thank you!

Command prompt
[image]

Comment: see this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596505/python-not-working-in-command-prompt

Comment: try ```python3 -V```

Comment: or try just ```py -v```

Comment: Your `python` command doesn't look like it's pointing to anything.  If it was right it would have initialized the interpreter and given you a `>>>` prompt.  Perhaps you are thinking `py`?

Comment: What's the output of `where python`?

Comment: Also, what is the output of `echo %PATH%`?

Comment: I also have windows and got the same behaviour you are describing. When using `py` instead of `python`, everything works

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 7):

On windows the python executable is `py.exe`, not `python.exe` (unless you are using a `venv`, which uses the latter to access).  Use `py` command instead, i.e. `py --version`.