# Python 3.9 pip install

Tags: python, pip, package

I recently downloaded and installed Python 3.9 because I wanted to run a website scraper to more easily organize recipes found online. However, when I try to run `pip` it says it doesn't recognize it (and I have tried editing the path but every video or site I find has different information).

Even a basic check of my Python version comes back with no results:

[image]

I have uninstalled and reinstalled Python 3.9 but to no avail. There is also no scripts file within my python file and my computer doesn't even seem to recognise that Python is installed.

Comment: Try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13596981/14510424.  My guess is you might have 2 versions of python installed and it doesn't know which to use?

Comment: Also did you tick these boxes on install? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54029728/14510424

Comment: please add the python path to environment variables

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python not working in command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596505/python-not-working-in-command-prompt)

Comment: I was having the same problem @smarotu, and for me uninstalling python and reinstalling it with add to PATH option checked, worked.

Answer (score 7):

In python 3.9 you can add below path(scripts path) to your environment variable

```
C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts
```

Once the path is added, open a fresh CMD window and type `pip --version`.

You can see your pip version `pip 20.2.4`

Answer (score 5):

I found that for Python 3.9 if you enter the command as `py -m pip install`,  the installation initiates as expected.

[Annotation 2021-06-17 121518_install pywinauto Visual Studio Code terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAB9S.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I finally can use pip install.
Here is how I do it:

1. Run python 3.6.9-adm64.exe
2. Choose Modify
3. Tick all boxes and click Next
4. Tick [Create shortcuts...appplication](not important) and Add Python to environment variables and click Install
5. Now run CMD and type:

   ```
   py -m pip install (name) //pygame for example
   ```

Now I installed pygame easily.

Answer (score 1):

On my windows laptop, python 3.9 was installed with the installer from python.org. I do not remember which options were checked but pip does not seem to be available in the `Scripts` folder.

```bash
> where python
C:\Python39\python.exe

> where pip
Information : impossible de trouver des fichiers pour le(s) modèle(s) spécifié(s).

> python -m pip --version
C:\Python39\python.exe: No module named pip
```

The following steps worked:

```bash
> python -m ensurepip
Looking in links: c:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\tmprd5o7bcb
Processing c:\users\<user>\appdata\local\temp\tmprd5o7bcb\setuptools-56.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
Processing c:\users\<user>\appdata\local\temp\tmprd5o7bcb\pip-21.1.3-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip
Successfully installed pip-21.1.3 setuptools-56.0.0

> python -m pip --version
pip 21.1.3 from C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)

> pip3 --version
pip 21.1.3 from c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)
```

Note that the `pip` alias does not seem to be installed by `ensurepip`, so I need to use `pip3` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by running `apt-get install python3-pip`
on my Debian Linux.

Comment: This may be fine for Linux, but you can see in the screenshot posted as part of the question that Windows is used here. And `apt-get` is certainly not the way to go for on a Windows system.

Comment: We're talking about windows here

Answer (score 0):

> every video or site I find has different information

This may be due to the fact that those sites provide information for different Python versions.

As Alfie Hanks already pointed out in the comments: The right way to do it is to check the box `Add Python 3.x to PATH` when installing Python 3 for the first time. When re-running the installer / re-installing choose "Modify" and check the box `Add Python to environment variables`. That takes care of setting the correct environment variable so that the Python and pip binary can be found by Windows.

If you have trouble finding those options, take a look at circlepi314's answer to a similar Python question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54029728/6710751 This one has screenshots of the installer where those options are marked.

Answer (score -1):

Install python again and when the prompt window opens, click on the modify button. Then check if pip is checked. If not then check it and then proceed with the install.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRNNI.png)

If it still doesn't work, simply uninstall python. And then when you reinstall it make sure that the ADD to path checkbox is checked.

Comment: That comes ticked by default, this problem is a bug in pip that's been there for ages, not related to the install process

Answer (score -3):

I had the similar problem, I managed to solve it with the following:

I installed python 3.9 by Brew on my Mac, so the pip3 was broken

I resolved by uninstalling python3.9 and installing 3.8

Comment: Completely changing the python version doesn't seem to be an acceptable answer.