# Installing python 3.9 in node 14

Tags: python, node.js, operating-system, bitbucket

recently i am using node:14 docker image and i want to install python 3.9 on it
I tried npm I python3 and python3 --version showed version 3.7, how should I install version 3.9?

Comment: go on this link **[How to install python 3.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64511066/python-3-9-pip-install)**