# Can't compile cpp and python file in vs code

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-code

I can compile and see the result from cpp file in vs code. But, but when I try compile python file by pressing Ctrl+Alt+N I can't see the result. I can see result only with right click and choosing Run Python file in terminal, as you can see in pictures. I want to compile smoothly cpp and python files in vs code. Is it possible?

[image: pic1:]

[image: pic2:]

[image: pic3:]

[image: pic4:]

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+N isn't a vscode builtin keyboard shortcut, it might only be provided by your C++ extension.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python not working in command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596505/python-not-working-in-command-prompt)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen "Python was not found" in Croatian; so yeah it looks like a path issue. OP, see the 2nd answer in the dupe question

Comment: I installed Python and selected python intrerpreter but it doesnt' work when I compile. I can run it only by run python file in terminal. I think you can't run cpp and python files in one vs code. You have to choose is it your vs code will be for c++ or python.

Comment: Have you properly set the `launch.json`, `settings.json`? And are the compiler/interpretor paths properly set?

Comment: You might want to go through [C++ Tut](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) and [Python Tut](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial)

Comment: Now it works, I dunno what I did. I think that when I installed python through MS store it started working. The problem was keyword python in cmd, cos py is the correct key word. When I installed python through MS store, now keyword python is also good. So strange.