# python --version not working on Windows command prompt but installed

Tags: python, windows, installation, pip

there I'm trying to install pip and have begun by installing python. I've installed python via an exe. However when I do basic things such as checking the version it says not found. I can run python in the command prompt by typing `py`.

However when it type: `python --version` it says not found? I've also tried `python3 --version` and using a capital P, to no avail?  as such running py get-pip.py is not working stating not found. please can someone assist?

Comment: can you add a screenshot?

Comment: " ive installed python via an exe." - from where did you get said installer? If you can start python by typing `py` then you should do `import sys; print(sys.executable)` to find python. Then you can add the location to your system PATH environment variable.

Comment: *"I can run python in the command prompt by typing `py`."* - *"as such running py get-pip.py is not working"* - You will have to provide a consistent problem statement if you are looking for help. Probably a good idea to take the [tour], and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should reinstall it. Probably it is because of the setup wizard

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a issue with Path variables. Try this : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596505/python-not-working-in-command-)

Answer (score 0):

Check if your environment variables are correctly set. Under "Path" there should be a line leading to your python folder somewhere. For me, the path is `"C:\Users\myUsername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\"`. You may need to restart your PC after changing something in the environment variables for it to take effect.

Comment: @CB2100 Here is a tutorial: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272416/how-to-add-a-folder-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows-10-with-screensho/44272417
But don't forget to restart your PC after setting it, may not work otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `py --version` to get the python version

[image]

To install `pip` use these commands

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
py get-pip.py
```

Comment: only issue is if i run the curl and py get commands i recive the following error: "Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases."

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66409838/8326080