# Python 3.10.6(64 bit) PATH

Tags: python, path, environment-variables

I've just installed python 3.10.6 and checked the box "Add python to your path"
and now when I open the cmd to check for python availability , I got python not found.
"**Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases**."
Any help please !!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python command not working in command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596505/python-command-not-working-in-command-prompt)

Answer (score 0):

Exit from current session or reboot (not recommended) and also you can set PATH for current cmd session: *set Path=full path to python.exe* but all others paths in current cmd PATH will be cleaned, so first may be check current PATH, then add item

check path from cmd by **echo %Path%** or PowerShell **$Env:Path**

Comment: I did like you said and know it gives me "Not recognized", however, I entered the variable environment and deleted the path I set, and surprisingly it worked. I don't know why or how

Comment: @AhmedAdel [SetEnvironmentVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/changing-environment-variables)