Python not recognized in laptop although it is installed
The python I have in my laptop did not compile any code. The error said

I checked the environment variables (path) and the list is as follows

I also checked the installed program list

I did not understand why Python is not recognized in my system.
Thank you for the help in advance.

Run $env:path to see if your python path is there in terminal.

This question is similar to: Python command not working in command prompt. You need to disable the link to the Windows Store https://stackoverflow.com/a/66490141/1527 in App execution aliases for your path to work

You have 3.7 in your path but 3.9 in your path associations and also a 3.11 python launcher. Does the 3.7 path really exist? Does a 3.9 path exist? I think you should clean out all of your pythons, make sure they are removed from path and file associations, then install again.

Make sure to add Python to PATH when installing it and use the py command in Command Prompt (since python links to the Microsoft store).

You also need the following line in your path variable:
C:\Users\cse_s\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\

The usual ways to check if the install is correct is as follows:
C:\Users\charl>python --version
Python 3.12.3

C:\Users\charl>python -V
Python 3.12.3

With Python Launcher installed:
py -V


if it actually exists. I see 3.7, 3.9 and 3.11 references. You shouldn't have to manually add a python path - the installer should do that.

I included "C:\Users\cse_s\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39" in the path variable but did not resolve the issue.

@Encipher, I have updated my answer above.
