# Downloading python 3 on windows

Tags: python

I am currently trying to figure out how to set up using python 3 on my machine (Windows 10 pro 64-bit), but I keep getting stuck.

I used the Python 3.6 downloader to install python, but whenever I try to use Command Prompt it keeps saying "'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" as if I have not yet installed it.

Unlike answers to previous questions, I have already added ";C:\Python36" to my Path environment variable, so what am I doing wrong?

I am relatively new to python, but know how to use it on my Mac, so please let me know if I'm just fundamentally confused about something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add python to cmd in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882808/how-can-i-add-python-to-cmd-in-windows)

Comment: Not a duplicate, I already set up the environment variables (which was their solution).

Answer (score 1):

In environmental variables under path, add your python path... you said you already so please ensure is their comma separation between previous path..

And once added save environment variables tab.  And close all command prompt then open it.

Then only command prompt will refresh with your python config..

Main thing,  if you enter **python** which mean python 2.

For python3 type, **python3** then it should work

Comment: I have the semicolon as a delimiter as described elsewhere online, I saved it, and I have restarted and nothing will work.

Comment: Did you tried python3? Python 3 should be launch by its version

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using command prompt? I just use the python shell that comes with IDLE. It’s much simpler.

If you have to use command prompt for some reason, you’re problem is probably that you need to type in python3. Plain python is what you use for using Python 2 in the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I ended up uninstalling and then re-downloading python, and selecting the button that says "add to environment variables." Previously, I typed the addition to Path myself, so I thought it might make a difference if I included it in the installation process instead. Then, I completely restarted my computer rather than just Command Prompt itself. I'm not sure which of these two things did it, but it works now!